# Understanding Log analytics from Synapse Azure SQL Auditing

Tags: azure-log-analytics, azure-synapse-analytics

I would like to get some understanding on the result set of the logs that are logged to log analytics from the Synapse dedicated SQL pool auditing.

What does it mean when 'Application name' column value says 'Data Integration-8330100a-8ee8-XXXX-XXXX-c326e88f7d94'.

Not sure what it means, initially I thought its a managed identity or something.

Answer (score 0):

> What does it mean when 'Application name' column value says 'Data Integration-8330100a-8ee8-XXXX-XXXX-c326e88f7d94'.

It's an **Application name** which is used to query the data source. as mentioned in below [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/audit-log-format?view=azuresql)

[image]

As you can see below the ***client Ip*** show in the Audit log is an IP of The ADF which is used to insert the data to, Synapse SQL So the Application name is a client temporary client application used by services to query the Synapse SQL

[image]